# dealing with cookies in development

Tags: reactjs, node.js, cookies

I have my code setup to use cookies in sessions but I can't get it to send the cookie as it keeps getting blocked by the browser since its a cross origin request (backend to frontend on different domains) and there just seems to be no way to get it to work as if I make my sameSite setting to be Lax then it won't send since its cross origin and if I make it none then I need secure to be true in which case I can't use it in development.

```js
app.use(session({
    name: 'session',
    store: new pgSessions({
        pool: db,
        tableName: 'session'
    }),
    secret: process.env.PG_SECRET,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: false,
    cookie: {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
        sameSite: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'None' : 'Lax',
    }
}))
```